# macOS NSStackView content does not fill the available space

Tags: macos, cocoa

I use a NSStackView to dynamically (added by code) display other NSViews, everything works so far, but the sub views are to small.

They try to be as small as possible, regardless the constrains, if i resize the views in IB, they scale correctly

The Header with the hide button does not fill the available space:

[image]

I did set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false on the stackview and all subviews

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it's hard to know for sure without more information, but the most likely cause is that the horizontal content hugging priority of the labels is higher than the horizontal hugging priority of the stack view. (Note: the former is a general property of all views while the latter is a stack-view-specific property.)

You also need to have constraints between the stack view and its superview to make the stack view stretch the full width. For example, leading and trailing space constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but in modern times I have found that if you set the alignment to width, everything magically works.

```swift
stackView.orientation = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .width
stackView.addArrangedSubview(nowFullWidthSubview)
```